# XML parsing using Jquery where format is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know the XML format. but i want to parse it from a given XMLObject using Jquery. Is it possible if yes then how to do that.

Comment: If you don't know the format, how do you know where to find the value you need? It seems like you should nail down the format first.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using JSONP to convert your XML to a JSON object.

This blog posts covers it nicely and saves me rewriting the code.
http://weedygarden.net/2011/01/consuming-remote-xml-as-jsonp/